# Docker rails mongodb NoServerAvailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am building a project with 3 docker.

- API with Rails
- Website angular / webpack
- DB with mongodb

So i have a `docker-compose` to handle everything.

My problem is when i want to seed my database, i have an error :

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No server is available matching  preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x47121755943460 tag_sets=[] server_selection_timeout=30 local_threshold=0.015>
```

I tried many thing, i am currently using the **beta version of Docker native on OSX**.

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build: web/
        ports:
            - "80:8080"
        links:
            - api
        depends_on:
            - api
        volumes:
            - ./web:/app
    api:
        build: api/
        command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
            - ./api:/app
            - ./api:/app/tmp/pids
        links:
            - db
        #depends_on:
            #- db
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment:
            RAILS_ENV: development
    db:
        image: mongo:3.2
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
```

My seeds.rb

```
require 'csv'

file = File.read("db/data.csv")
csv = CSV.parse(file, :headers => false, :col_sep => ";")

csv.each do |row|
    Datum.create(
        :country_code   => row[0],
        :country        => row[1]
    )
end
```

And my mongoid.yml It's normal i use localhost because with the beta version, it's on localhost. when i tried with docker-machine, i changed it to the docker ip.

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: api_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
  options:
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: api_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
```

Once my `docker-compose up -d` i try to rake with `docker-compose run api rake db:seed`

All the containers a running, and i can access to it from my navigator without a problem.

When i uninstall docker native and use boot2docker, it's working.

Did anyone have an idea where the problem is from ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
- db:27017
```

in your hosts configuration of the `mongoid.yml`, where "db" is the name of your mongo service in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, maybe i didn't worked on that project now, but i remember the error came from the `docker OSX Beta` instead of using `docker-machine`

Comment: I also noticed that you should rather use the mongo uri like `uri: mongodb://db:27017` instead of connecting via host and user parameters, cause Mongoid will not be able to authenticate otherwise.